# Subsetting an unnamed vector in R

Tags: r, vector, subset

I'm getting a vector of numbers as output from one function, and am wanting to drop all the values higher than 2900, then pipe the remainder directly into a second function. (They'll be sorted, if that helps.) Is there a clever way to do this seemingly simple thing without having to stop and define an intermediate variable?

Comment: Something like `x[x <= 2900]` will keep only the values you want. If you want to remove `NA`'s, if any, use `x[which(x <= 2900)]` instead. And pipe this result into the other function.

Comment: Perhaps an anonymous function? `f2((function(x) x[x <= 2900])(f1(input)))`? Or, since R 4.0.0, `input |> f1() |> (\(x) x[x <= 2900])() |> f2()` ...

Comment: The vector isn't named **x**, or anything -- that's the point!

Comment: Right, and in my example I have _not_ assigned the intermediate `f1(input)` to a name.

Comment: Thank you - very elegant! (I was responding to Rui Barradas before)

Comment: It probably won't make an important difference, but I'd guess creating the intermediate variable would be faster than not doing so.  Definitely would if you are using `magrittr` pipes, probably still would with the more efficient built-in pipe.  So why do you want a pipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way without creating a temp vector.

1. The functions `f` and `g` are simple test functions that output a sequence of integers from1 to their argument `n`. Function `g` assigns `NA` to half of the output vector.
2. Function `h` sums its input vector.
3. In the middle of the pipe, there's an anonymous function that subsets the output of `f` or `g` and pipes the resulting vector to function `h`.
4. In the case of the pipe from `g`, extra code is needed to remove `NA`'s, if that's what the user wants.

```r
f <- function(n) seq.int(n)
g <- function(n){
  y <- seq.int(n)
  is.na(y) <- sample(n, n/2)
  y
}
h <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) sum(x, na.rm = na.rm)

set.seed(2022)
f(3000) |> (\(x) x[x <= 2900])() |> h()
#> [1] 4206450

set.seed(2022)
g(3000) |> (\(x) x[x <= 2900])() |> h()
#> [1] NA

set.seed(2022)
g(3000) |> (\(x) x[x <= 2900])() |> h(na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] 2080026

set.seed(2022)
g(3000) |> (\(x) x[which(x <= 2900)])() |> h()
#> [1] 2080026
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Edit

Following [Mikael Jagan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71447723/subsetting-an-unnamed-vector-in-r/71447856#comment126285284_71447723), the input can be piped to the first function like below.

```r
input <- 3000
input |> f() |> (\(x) x[x <= 2900])() |> h()
#> [1] 4206450
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Is there a term for that notation? I haven't seen it before, and there's nothing obvious to google...

Comment: @VinnyB See `?\`|>\`` and `?\`function\``.

Comment: Thank you! I'm pretty new to all this.
I've been having to swap between computers a lot lately, and one of them hasn't updated RStudio in a while, so for now I've had to avoid using the nice solutions above. What I've settled on is: `na.omit(sapply(input %>% f, function(x) ifelse(x<2900,x,NA)))`

Answer (score 0):

**Second, simple, answer**

I made it far too complicated before (below the line). Maybe there's an application where something like that is useful, but all you need is dplyr's dot:

```
1:10 %>% .[. < 4]
# 1 2 3
```

---

**First, convoluted, answer**

A generic prewritten function let's you pipe an anonymous vector in and out whenever the occasion arises.

```
vsubset <- function(v, condition) v[eval(str2expression(paste("v", condition)))]

1:10 %>% vsubset("<5")                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# 1 2 3 4
```

To momentarily make it easier to understand, let's make three more basic versions:

```
equal_to <- function(v, equivalent) v[v == equivalent]
1:10 %>% equal_to(4)
# 4

less_than <- function(v, threshold) v[v < equivalent]
1:10 %>% less_than(4)
# 1 2 3

greater_than <- function(v, threshold) v[v > equivalent]
1:10 %>% less_than(4)
# 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I prefer, though, to only have one widely-applicable function. After all, these three are very incomplete: we at least still need `<=`, `>=` and `!=`.

To do so, we

1. write the condition as a string (e.g. `"==3"`)
2. combine it with the in-function name of the vector using `paste()`
3. turn the string into an expression with `str2expression()`
4. run the expression with `eval()`

There very well may be a more efficient approach than `eval(str2expression(paste(..)))` but this has worked for me.